# service call isms 6 s16 "17079876543" i32 0 i32 0 s16 "SMS TEXT HERE" not send multipart sms

Tags: android, command-line, sms, adb, send

i must send multipart Sms 
but this code not send it

service call isms 5 s16 "17079876543" i32 0 i32 0 s16 "SMS TEXT HERE"
tyied it but not working

:( please help me